# iPhone 6 media query

Tags: html, css, iphone, media-queries

I can't get the media queries for iPhone 6+ in landscape orientation to function properly. Portrait is working just fine.
I'm using `@media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:568px) and (orientation: landscape) {}` for iPhone 5 and `@media only screen and (min-width:414px) and (max-width:736px) and (orientation: landscape) {}` for iPhone 6+ - but then the iPhone 5 changes to what I've written for iPhone 6+ instead. And the iPhone 6+ doesn't change until I change `736px` width to `800px`width.

I've tried lots of different stuff found here on stack overflow but nothing works. And for some reason min/max-DEVICE-width doesn't work for me.

I'm using the Responsive Web Design Tester for Google Chrome to test (I haven't got an iPhone 6+ to test with).
And I've got `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">` in my `<head>` tag.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

media query for iphone 6

```
/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}
```

here you find great tutorial about it https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Unfortunately, as I wrote, (min-device-width) isn't working for me at all. Nothing happens.

Comment: @soulitude above code is well tested and used by all of us to target iphone 6 to see it worked for u open chrome press `F12` then `Ctrl + shift + m` and select iphone 6 and refresh ur page